# Get keys from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i have selectbox to show from javascript array.

```
<h6><strong>Brand</strong></h6>
  <select data-placeholder="Brand..."  multiple id="brand" style="width:200px;height:50px;margin: 0;">
    <script language="javascript">print_brand1("brand");</script>
  </select>
```

But when i choose one of selectbox data then it get values. Here is javascript code

```
var brand_arr = new Array(
1:"Acer",
2:"Dell"
);

function print_brand1(brand_id){
var option_str = document.getElementById(brand_id);
option_str.length=0;
option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
for (var i=0; i<brand_arr.length; i++) {
option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(brand_arr[i],brand_arr[i]);
}
}
```

How do i get keys (not values) when i choose one of selectbox data?

Comment: Your code does not work, you should be using an object (ie surround your key-value pairs with `{` and `}`) instead of the Array constructor.

Comment: This code is really bad. This cant work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work in its current state, however if you insist on keeping your current array structure you would need:

```
var brand_arr = {
    1: "Acer",
    2: "Dell"
};
```

Which syntactically makes little sense, assigning a key of 1/2 makes little sense when you could just get this number by using the current index + 1.

Note that with the changes above, in order to assign the keys `1` and `2` we are having to iterate over a Javascript Object and not a Javascript Array.

If you wanted to print `1` and `2` you could then do:

```
for(var k in brand_arr) {
    if(brand_arr.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        console.log(k); // key
        console.log(brand_arr[k]); // value
    }
}
```

Although this answers your problem, I would still consider the structure of your data, it would make much more sense to have something like:

```
var brand_arr = [
    { brand: 'Acer', price: 200 },
    { brand: 'Dell', price: 200 }
];
```

Note how in the above example we can add extra details about that brand in the JSON. We could then iterate over the brand array to get more detail about each brand in a much more readable format opposed to a user assigned index and its name.